# Extension Method for a Collection of Derived Types with Base Type in Method Signature

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, c#-3.0

I want to write an extension method for a collection of objects that uses base class as a type requirement.  I understand this is not necessarily the best way to do things, but I am curious because I'm interested in learning the nuances of the language.  This example explains what I would  like to do.

```
public class Human { public bool IsHappy { get; set; } }
public class Man : Human { public bool IsSurly { get; set; } }
public class Woman : Human { public bool IsAgreeable { get; set; } }

public static class ExtMethods
{
    public static void HappinessStatus(this IEnumerable<Human> items)
    {
        foreach (Human item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.IsHappy.ToString());
        }
    }
}

// then in some method, I wish to be able to do the following

List<Woman> females = RetreiveListElements(); // returns a list of Women
females.HappinessStatus(); // prints the happiness bool from each item in a collection
```

The only way I can get the extension method to expose is to create a collection of Humans.  Is it possible to call this type of extension method on derived types as long as I only reference members of the base type?

Comment: It works in .Net 4, but not in earlier versions. The tag on the question says c#3.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code will actually compile as is with the C# 4 compiler, as that version supports [contravariant type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

To get it working with C# 3, you can create a generic extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` with a `where T : Human` constraint that acts on the generic type, instead of specifically only for `IEnumerable<Human>`:

```
public static void HappinessStatus<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) where T : Human
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.IsHappy.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you can call the extension method on your `List<Woman>` collection as you describe.

Comment: This does work, but I created a generic list of strings and this method exposes itself to a list of strings.  Is there a way for this method only to be exposed when a collection of Human or derived type of Human is being used?

Comment: @Nate: I don't think so. In either case, the code in your question and my answer both work (I just tested your question code too), and both will simply not compile if you try to call it on a list of non-Humans.

Comment: I now understand why many people are against extension methods of this type, it is poor form to expose a method on a collection that won't compile.

Comment: @Nate: My bad, the code in your question works if compiled as C# 4.0. It doesn't compile as C# 3.0. Ironic, because I wrote my answer **knowing** you were looking for a 3.0 solution...

Comment: @Nate - "I created a generic list of strings and this method exposes itself to a list of strings" <- Can you explain what you mean by this? Do you mean that it is available in intellisense?

Comment: @saus, yes, that is exactly what I meant, it is available in intellisense.