# How to create an extension method that works with a subclass of a nested type parameter?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, extension-methods, type-parameter

I'm having trouble accessing an extension method I've created that takes an object with a base class as its type parameter.

Here's the base class:

```vb
Namespace Models.Db
  Public Class Base
    Public Property Id As Integer
  End Class
End Namespace
```

...and the subclass:

```vb
Namespace Models.Db
  Public Class City
    Inherits Base

    ...

  End Class
End Namespace
```

Here's the extension method:

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports Matrix.Models
Imports Moq

Public Module Extensions
  <Extension>
  Public Sub SetupMock(Instance As Mock(Of DbSet(Of Db.Base)), Entities As List(Of Db.Base))
    Instance.As(Of IQueryable(Of Db.Base)).Setup(Function(Cities) Cities.GetEnumerator).Returns(Entities.GetEnumerator)
    Instance.As(Of IQueryable(Of Db.Base)).Setup(Function(Cities) Cities.ElementType).Returns(Entities.AsQueryable.ElementType)
    Instance.As(Of IQueryable(Of Db.Base)).Setup(Function(Cities) Cities.Expression).Returns(Entities.AsQueryable.Expression)
    Instance.As(Of IQueryable(Of Db.Base)).Setup(Function(Cities) Cities.Provider).Returns(Entities.AsQueryable.Provider)
  End Sub
End Module
```

...and here's the calling code:

```vb
Private Function GetDbContextMock() As Mock(Of Db.Context)
  Dim oCitiesMock As Mock(Of DbSet(Of Db.City))

  oCitiesMock = New Mock(Of DbSet(Of Db.City))
  oCitiesMock.SetupMock(Me.Cities) ' Me.Cities is a List(Of Db.City)
End Function
```

The compile-time error is:

> 'SetupMock' is not a member of 'Mock(Of DbSet(Of City))'

However, when I change the calling code to this:

```vb
  Dim oCitiesMock As Mock(Of DbSet(Of Db.Base))
  oCitiesMock = New Mock(Of DbSet(Of Db.Base))
```

...the extension method is found. But I need to send a subclass reference to the extension method, not a base class reference.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1217600) indicates that it's possible with simple superclass/subclass objects, but as this is dealing with type parameters it's a bit more complex.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5428178) seemed at first like it might provide a solution, but upon further reflection it addresses only one level of type parameters. The code above has two. I'm not sure if this nuance makes a difference, but at the end of the day the code doesn't compile.

Can this be done in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second linked answer was on the right track.  The extra 'level' of typing doesn't really matter.  The key point of that answer is including the generic (`<T>` in C#, `(Of T)` in VB) when defining the extension method using derived types.  Your initial code didn't do that - it was hard-coding to expect the base type.

When using generics this way, you can add a constraint so that `T` must inherit the desired base type.  (Technically this works for any generic method, so it's convenient that extension methods also work this way.)

See below, presented as console app for easy testing:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim mock As New Mock(Of [Set](Of Derived))
        mock.SetupMock(New List(Of Derived))

        'also compiles, uses same extension
        Dim mockBase As New Mock(Of [Set](Of Base))
        mockBase.SetupMock(New List(Of Base))
    End Sub
End Module

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension>
    Public Sub SetupMock(Of T As Base)(Instance As Mock(Of [Set](Of T)), Entities As List(Of T))
        'do stuff with Entities
    End Sub
End Module

'simple class definitions to illustrate the example
Public Class Base : End Class
Public Class Derived
    Inherits Base
End Class
Public Class [Set](Of T) : End Class
Public Class Mock(Of T) : End Class
```

If your entities list is always a list of the Base type, but just happens to be populated with the derived type, you can instead define the extension method with `Entities As List(Of Base)`, but then your list had better always be `List(Of Base)` and not `List(Of T)`.

Comment: That was it, thank you. I ended up having to choose between `Entities As List(Of T)` and `Entities As IEnumerable(Of Db.Base)`. I went with the former. It looks sexier.

Comment: @InteXX IEnumerable(Of T) is even more flexible.  (I tried hard to pun flex and sexy; nothing good came of it.)

Comment: @InteXX note that `IEnumerable` is variant in its parameters (I believe you can use an `IEnumerable(Of Derived)` where an `IEnumerable(Of Base)` is expected---I forget if this is covariance or contravariance).  Variance might come into play here, I'd recommend doing a little reading on it.

Comment: Actually, in the end I wasn't able to use either one. Two of my entities—`Role` and `User`—don't derive from `Base`, but rather from `IdentityRole` and `IdentityUser`, respectively. Code elsewhere, that I can't change, explicitly requires the `Db.Role` and `Db.User` types, so I had to skip the extension method approach altogether. But yes, during my casting about I did notice that `IEnumerable(Of T)` seemed to work better. Thanks for the mention. | @Craig

Comment: OK, I was able to bring back the extension method. I modified the method's type parameters from `Setup(Of TEntity As Db.Base)` to `Setup(Of TEntity As Class)`. This handles `Db.Base` as well as `IdentityRole` and `IdentityUser`. It works well. | @Craig